# Does the Google Cast extension for Google Chrome support 1080p?

Tags: google-cast

In the Options for the Google Cast extension under 'Tab projection quality', there are three options:

Extreme (720p high bitrate)
 High (720p)
 Standard (480p)

1080p is not listed.

I assume if I play a 1080p video that it will work because it's sending the video url to Chromecast, but am I limited to 720p for regular HTML webpages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be more of a user question, not a development question.

The Google Cast extension for Chrome provides two major functions:

1. Chrome Mirroring - which is limited to 720p - This acts by encoding your tab to WebM/Opus and then sending to the Chromecast device.
2. The Google Cast API for Chrome which allows your webpage to cast a video to a Chromecast device.  Which, of course can be full 1080p.  [Official documentation](http://developers.google.com/cast).

Comment: Will the Chrome Mirroring always be limited to 720p?

Comment: @dovdukes I'm going to assume for the time-being; think about latency and encoding overhead for a screen at 1080p!