# Can we implement Miracast functionality in google_cast

Tags: google-cast

Can we implement or tie in miracast functionality into chrome cast? Or configure the receiver to accept miracast content?

Comment: No Miracast functionality - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842749/does-the-google-cast-extension-for-google-chrome-support-1080p

Answer (score 2):

**Update: Miracast is actually supported now. See [here](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2865484?hl=en).**

=====

Miracast probably never will be supported on the ChromeCast (without some sort of hack). However, a little workaround does exist. If you're just wanting to stream video, just drag/load the video into a Chrome tab and use the [ChromeCast extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd) to steam that video content to your device. It should work with any files that Chrome itself supports (PDF, images, etc). Hope that helps.

Comment: That link claiming Miracast support appears to say that Android now supports streaming to Miracast receivers in addition to Chromecast. Chromecast devices still don't function as Miracast receivers.

Comment: Is there no way to dual boot/ hack Chrome cast with Miracast Firmware? After all there are 10/15$ dongles from China that do Miracast etc. So, why not?