# Send content to chromecast from native application

Tags: google-cast

Is it possible to send video to the chromecast device from a native application?  It would be nice to share any window on a system instead of only chrome tabs.  Also, is there any documentation of the communication used by chrome to communicate with the chromecast?  It is my understanding that the chromecast essentially loads content from an embedded chrome instance, but there appears to be more direct ways of communicating with the device since it is able to stream content from a chrome tab using the extension.

Answer (score 1):

*From how I understand the Chromecast architecture:*

You can display any URL you want on the TV (you have to [whitelist your app](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting#whitelist-receiver) and register the URL first). It must be a URL. This can include HTML, JS, CSS, etc. Anything that is already on the internet.

To receive data from a device (say, the URL of a video to load), you must implement logic to interpret messages from channels. These messages are encoded as JSON, which makes it difficult to send videos or pictures (binary data). It is obviously easiest to upload things like this to some website, and have the receiver display them.

People have asked, "well, then how does the tab/screen sharing work?" The JSON encoding is just what Google provides in their SDK. In their own source, they don't have this restriction.

**Update**:
It turns out you can actually [stream local videos](http://www.droid-life.com/2013/07/25/tip-you-can-play-local-video-files-through-chromecast/) to your TV by just opening the local file in Chrome, and then casting that to your TV.

Comment: It should be possible to create a webm stream using libvpx, libopus, and libwebm, (VLC actually supports streaming out of the box, don't recall what formats it supports for this though) and then host the video on some port, and have the embedded chrome connect to it.  The only question is how to control the browser on the chromecast without the provided APIs for android, ios, or chrome.

Comment: On another note, ideally you would use WebRTC to stream the video, and I'm fairly certain VLC wouldn't support that (you could just use libjingle though).

Comment: It should be possible, but Cast SDK doesn't give you direct access to the channel. That doesn't mean that you can't stream over it though.

Comment: I'll bet that only the Chrome cast extension is whitelisted to stream WebM/Opus content to the receiver device. You might be able to modify the extension or copy parts of it to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to whitelist your receiver device if you are developing a receiver application. That would be a Chome app that runs on the receiver's Chrome instance.

You need to whitelist a sender url if you are developing a Chrome app that will cast it's contents.

Video casting works by sending a url to the receiver device, which the device will load directly.

Tab casting works by encoding the tab contents using WebM/Opus (in the Chrome cast extension) and streaming that to the receiver device. (This is limited to 720p, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842749/does-the-google-cast-extension-for-google-chrome-support-1080p))

Chrome apps can only use Video casting.

The chrome cast extension is going to be the only way to stream directly to the device.

So the answer to your question is no, you cannot stream video directly to the device. The receiver must load the video from the url you provide.

There is some speculation whether the receiver can be provided with a local url or if it must already be available on the internet. This has yet to be clarified.